# Is there a way to get a minimal / lite version of three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

With only the features I need?  The regular minified version is 411KB!

I suppose I could setup the build process myself and manually remove unused packages, but maybe someone has done this already?

Comment: Seems to be only 103KB on [cdnjs hosted](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js), that could be that I'm using a Linux OS through. The size isn't that large, is it taking too long to load?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek depends whether you're looking at the gzipped or original size of the file, but given that most 3D things will be loaded for quite a while, I doubt it's much of an issue.

Comment: There is an unofficial builder for three.js: http://marcinwieprzkowicz.github.io/three.js-builder/

Comment: Andreas's answer should be put as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an unofficial builder for three.js:
http://marcinwieprzkowicz.github.io/three.js-builder/

But it would also be possible to clone the git repository and create your own customized build script (the description is deprecated but maybe the example build scripts could give you enough infos):
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/build.py,-or-how-to-generate-a-compressed-Three.js-file